# Blueprint CSS Framework: Para moves to right side

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I am using Blueprint CSS framework and I have the following code for para in my screen.css file

```
p {margin:0 0 1.5em;}
.left {float:left !important;}
 p .left {margin:1.5em 1.5em 1.5em 0;padding:0;}
.right {float:right !important;}
p .right {margin:1.5em 0 1.5em 1.5em;padding:0;}
```

Now because of the above code(I guess) when I use para in my website I get the following formatting:

```
para One
     para two
     para three
```

INSTEAD of

```
para One
para two
para three
```

Could you please tell me how to fix the problem.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: can you please give the example of your code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: THanks khurram for your reply. I pasted some of my codes on jsfiddle and interestingly it worked okay there. May be because I couldn't paste all the codes. But if you see this blueprint's official demo template(http://blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/sample.html) which is actually built using Blueprint CSS framework, you would see that the problem also exists there. please check the source code of that template for details.(Press Ctrl+U)

Comment: There probably *is* no problem, this is working as intended. In the `screen.css` file there's a rule `p + p { text-indent: 2em; }` which is meant to... well err... indent each `p` that follows another `p`.

Comment: @Jeroen could you please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as correct. I have deleted the screen.css and its working just the way I wanted. :)

Comment: @black_belt okidoki done that, thx :) and glad to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `screen.css` file contains a rule that creates this effect:

```
p + p {
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

This means that every `p` following another `p` will be indented by 2em.

If you remove that (or the entire file of course :D) then the paragraphs won't indent anymore.

Answer (score 0):

in the tutorial above you pasted the [Link](http://blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/sample.html), there is class used at the second para that is

```
.<div class="span-15 prepend-1 colborder">
```

just remove the class "prepend-1" from that div, because there is padding-left in it.

```
.prepend-1
{
padding-left:40px;
}
```

sorry for bad english!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed the prepend-1 but still it didn't work, but however I have managed to got the result I wanted by removing the blueprint/plugins/fancy-type/screen.css